# How to break while loop in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I create a data logger from arduinio to python and I want to display the data using Kivy,

I try using while loop in my project but every time I close the app the app hang because the while loop still running, so I plan to add button that will break the loop but its not working,

or if anyone have other way please let me know

this my my coding for .py

```
import serial
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import mainthread
import threading
from time import sleep
import time
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock

class NaviWindow(Screen):
    temp_text = StringProperty("")
    humid_text = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NaviWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        threading.Thread(target=self.tmhm).start()

    def tmhm(self):
        flag = True
        while flag==True:
            with serial.Serial('COM3', 115200) as ser:
                data = str(ser.readline().strip().decode())
                ser.close()
                self.update_values(data.split(","))
        
            time.sleep(60)


    @mainthread
    def update_values(self, data):
        self.temp_text = data[0]
        self.humid_text = data[1]



class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kys = Builder.load_file("temp4.kv")

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

and here my .kv file

```
WindowManager:
    NaviWindow:

<NaviWindow>:

    orientation:'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
    Label:
        text: "Temperature"
        font_size: 30
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.17)
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0.8}
    Label:
        text: "every 1 minutes"
        font_size: 15
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.17)
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0.7}

            
    Label:
        text: "Humidity"
        font_size: 30
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.17)
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.8}

    Label:
        text: "every 1 minutes"
        font_size: 15
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.17)
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.7}

    Label:
        text:root.temp_text
        font_size: 20
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.17)
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0.5}


    Label:
        text: root.humid_text
        font_size: 20
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.17)
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.5}


    Button:

        size_hint: (1, 0.17)
        pos_hint: {'x': 0}
        text:"Close App"
        on_release: app.close_application()
```

Comment: The problem is that `time.sleep(60)` will hang all execution for 60 seconds.  Instead of time.sleep(), maybe you can restructure this to use `kivy.Clock.schedule_interval(callback_func, 60)`?

Comment: Add `daemon=True` to your `Thread`.